# Saber qué dependencias son necesarias instalar para una determinada aplicación en Python bajo Linux

Tags: python, linux, dependencias

Quisiera saber qué dependencias son necesarias instalar para poder ejecutar correctamente un determinado script Python por cualquier usuario en Linux. Es decir, cada distribución Linux viene con unos paquetes instalados por defecto. Yo, cuando desarrollo una aplicación sé qué paquetes he necesitado instalar, **pero no sé si otra persona necesitará instalar algún paquete adicional porque mi distribución (Ubuntu) ya lo incluía por defecto o porque ese paquete se había instalado previamente**.

Por ejemplo, hace unos días creé un script con Python que utilizaba wxPython, el binding de la librería wxWidgets. Como el equipo donde lo hice tenía instalado wxGlade, ya tenía instalada la dependencia `python-wxgtk3.0`
y sus "sub-dependencias" y me encontré con el problema desconocer la necesidad de instalar previamente esas dependencias.

Sé cómo saber qué dependencias necesita un determinado paquete deb, por ejemplo `apt-cache depends wxglade` me devuelve:

```
wxglade
  Depende: python
  Depende: python-wxgtk3.0
  Entra en conflicto: <python-wxglade>
  Reemplaza: <python-wxglade>
```

Pero no sé si existe alguna técnica o algo similar para Python que me diga que paquetes son necesarios para poder ejecutar un script.

Answer (score 1):

Es prácticamente imposible controlar las *"dependencias"* que tenga un script de python (o cualquier otro paquete) ya que cada distribución empaqueta los módulos y librerías de modo diferente.

Además, hay dependencias que no tiene solución sencilla. Por ejemplo, si tu aplicación requiere gtk-3, no vas a poder usarla en linux LTS a fecha de hoy, ya que usan gtk-2.8, y seguirán así por varios años más. Si instalas gtk-3 en estos sistemas, seguramente romperías todas las herramientas que viene por defecto.

Como solución, se han propuesto diferentes sistemas de paquetes que gestionan sus dependencias en entorno de usuario como son [flatpak](http://flatpak.org/), Snaps y AppImage. No quiero entrar en ventajas o incovenientes (que no es la misión de este foro). Estas soluciones se están empezando a usar en linuxmint, ubuntu e, incluso, windows10. La desventaja es que, un script de unos kilobytes, puede que requiera instalar unos cientos de megas de dependencias para ejecutarse. Pero es una solución aceptable.

Otra solución sería usar docker, donde tu script se ejecutaría en un contenedor con todas las dependencias que necesite. Lejos de ser una solución costosa en recursos, hoy en día es bastante habitual para entornos de desarrollo.

Volviendo a python, [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/) se ha convertido en un *estándar de facto* para instalar módulos de python (también R, ruby, scala,...), así como las librerías necesarias para el sistema operativo en cuestión. Si creas un entorno virtual e instalas en él las dependencias, luego es relativamente fácil replicar este entorno en otro sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Hasta ahora no conozco ningún método específico para conocer las dependencias de paquetes en Python además de manejar la respuesta de los errores.

Generalmente la consola de Linux y Python maneja bastante bien las excepciones. Es considerado como buenas practicas trabajar sobre entornos virtuales o contenedores para así poder controlar las dependencias y paquetes de una forma mucho mas eficiente. Si ves que la exception del error solicita un paquete en especifico intenta crear una entorno virtual ( ya sea con el los paquetes de [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) o con [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) ), instalar los paquetes dentro el entorno virtual y probar.

Algo interesante de los paquetes de virtualenv o de anaconda es que puedes registrar los paquetes de python que usas en un archivo de texto.

Para registrarlos debes estar en el entorno virtual y activarlo:

```
$ source activate {nombre de tu entorno virtual}
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Y para instalarlos:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```